# Unable to select values when using a parameter for the column name

Tags: sql, vb.net, parameterized-query

```
Try
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        SQL = "SELECT @PARAM FROM SystemOps"
        sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, connection)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@PARAM", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = "SystemNavn"
        ' .. and so on...
```

When I run the code, it returns with a result of `"SystemNavn"` (which is the name of the column in the table), instead of the value of that column in the current row.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use parameter names for column names, or any other SQL syntax.  You can only use parameters as placeholders for literal values.  Parameters always get replaced with the literal form for the value, so in your example, the command which is being run, essentially, gets evaluated as:

```
SELECT 'SystemNavn` FROM SystemOps
```

In order to have a variable column name, like that, I would recommend dynamically building the SQL string, like this:

```
Dim columnName As String = "SystemNavn"
SQL = "SELECT [" & columnName & "] FROM SystemOps"
```

However, by doing so, you are opening yourself up to potential SQL-injection attacks, so you need to be careful.  The safest way, that I'm aware of, to avoid an attack in a situation like this is to get the list of column names from the database and compare the `columnName` variable against that list to ensure that it is actually a valid column name.

Of course, if the column name never changes, then there's no reason to make it a variable at all.  In that case, just hard-code it directly into the SQL command, thereby avoiding the necessity for parameters or variables at all:

```
SQL = "SELECT SystemNavn FROM SystemOps"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't need any parameters in this case.  just do

```
SQL = "SELECT SystemNavn FROM SystemOps"
```

This is secure.  If later you need to filter this, you can do something like:

```
SQL = "SELECT SystemNavn FROM SystemOps WHERE COL_A = @ColA"
```

FYI, for your code above, since it is a VARCHAR type, it is being executed like so:

```
SELECT 'SystemNavn' FROM SystemOps
```

That is why you're getting 'SystemNavn' back.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter to specify the name of a column or a table.

The parameters collection are used to specify the values to search for, to insert, to update or delete.

Your code should be changed to something like this

```
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()
        SQL = "SELECT SystemNavn, <other fiels if needed> " & _
              "FROM SystemOps WHERE <keyfield_name> = @PARAM"
        sqlCmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, connection)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAM", paramValue)
        ......
    End Using
```

Of course the example above assumes that you have a WHERE clause, if you want to retrieve every value of the column SystemNavn without condition, then you don't need a parametrized query because every part of your sql command is provided by you and there is no worry for sql injection.

Comment: So how can I make a parameterized query for selecting data from database ? 
Or if now with parameterization, then how do I make selecting query safe against injections ?

Comment: It is explained in the code above. You should know the column names that you want to get back. Your user type the text to search for and you get this inout and build a parameter. The framework ensure that the typed text is legitimate and pass to the database engine the correct parameter value that is compared against the values in the searched field

Comment: But as have only one row in the table (and this will not change in future) I am not filtering the queried value with `WHERE` so I should simply NOT use parameters. Right ? And my code should be simply:

`sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT SystemNavn FROM SystemOPs"


            reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()


            reader.Read()`

But is there a way of securing my case of query or it is secure enough ?

Comment: Exactly, in a simple SELECT query without a where  clause there is no need to parametrize anything.

Comment: Secure from what? No sql injection possible here. If you have sensitive data in your database then it is better to focalize on the database access to allow only trusted user the ability to connect and emit sql statements.

Comment: @Steve Focalize?  That's a new one to me.  Does that have the same meaning as the verb "focus", or does it have some kind of special meaning?  Either way, I like it :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart yes sorry sometime I forget to check on Google translate. Give me a word maker license for a moment :))