# Bulk Data update in a windows application using SQL update procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I've created a windows application to display the data from SQL database to a gridview in a windows application. I used VB.net and SQL server to do that. While using where condition in the sql query I got the values which satisfies given data. Now I need to update the shown data. For that I used the sql query Update columnName = value where (the condition). the column name and value are got from the user using a textbox. When i used the query in Sql, it works fine and the value gets updated in database. But, When I run the same in VB code it doesn't gets updated in the windows application. I doesn't get it, and the assigned time for it runs beyond my watch time. Please, help me someone. Thanks in advance.Here I attach the code.

\ the code starts here \

```
Private Sub Btn_Edit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Update.Click
        cmdupdate.Connection = connection
        connection.Open()
        'table.Rows.Clear()
        'table.Columns.Clear()

 cmdupdate.CommandText = "update tblWebaccessErrorTrack set @columnName = @editData where IssueDateTime between @frmdate and @todate and ErrorDetails like '%' + @errorDetails + '%' and  ClientIpaddress like '%'+ @IpAddress + '%' and ResponseStatus like '%'+ @responseStatus + '%' and TicketNo like '%' + @ticketNo + '%' select * from tblWebaccessErrorTrack"
        table.Clear()
        '"UPDATE tblWebaccessErrorTrack
        ' SET
        ' @columnName = @editData"
        '"sp_Updatedata"
        'Update tblWebaccessErrorTrack set TicketNo=202010 select * from tblWebaccessErrorTrack

        'cmdupdate.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@frmdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = frm_DateTimePicker.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@todate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = to_DateTimePicker.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@errorDetails", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtErrorDetails.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@IpAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtClientIp.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@responseStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtResponseStatus.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@ticketNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTicketNo.Text
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@columnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Columnvalue '//column name
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@editData", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEditdata.Text '//Data we give

        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdupdate)

        adapter.Fill(table)
        adapter.Update(table)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        'adapter.Fill(table)
        'table.Clear()


        'cmdupdate.CommandText = "select * from tblWebaccessErrorTrack" 'where IssueDateTime between @frmdate and @todate and ErrorDetails like '%' + @errorDetails + '%' and  ClientIpaddress like '%'+ @IpAddress + '%' and ResponseStatus like '%'+ @responseStatus + '%' and TicketNo like '%' + @ticketNo + '%'"
        'adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdupdate)
        'adapter.Fill(table)
        'adapter.Update(table)
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = table
        ''adapter.Fill(table)
        ''cmdupdate.Parameters.Clear()
        'table.Clear()
        connection.Close()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()

    End Sub`enter code here`
```

- the character(') present in front of some line represents commented line.

Comment: You can't use a parameter for a column name. [Can I pass column name as input parameter in SQL stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092869/can-i-pass-column-name-as-input-parameter-in-sql-stored-procedure) has useful suggestions.

Comment: This is not a stored procedure so Andrew is incorrect.  Update will only work if the data is in the database.  You need to use Insert for new rows.

Comment: @jdweng SP or not, you can't use a parameter for a column name (`set @columnName = @editData` in the question). The SP aspect is incidental.

Comment: Why not?  This is SQL Server which accepts column names.

Comment: @jdweng The column name cannot be a parameter. It's in the documentation: [UPDATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). `SET column_name = expression` doesn't allow for column_name to be an expression; an  expression includes a parameter.

Comment: @user12661874 Also, there seems to be `select * from tblWebaccessErrorTrack` tacked onto the end of the `update` command.

Comment: Stored Procedure is commented out.  If column name is actually a field in the table, then the code is valid.  And column name is not in the command text.

Comment: @jdweng I am referring to the (outdented) line which starts `cmdupdate.CommandText = `, not the similar commented-out line later on. See Steven Doggart's answer at [Unable to select values when using a parameter for the column name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16419380/1115360) if you'd like a second opinion.

Comment: With all those Like parameters are you expecting to update several rows? If not retrieve the Primary Key and identify the record to update with that.

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if the code is split up into smaller pieces which each do one thing. It makes understanding and updating the code simpler. So, the methods to update a column and show the DGV would be separate.

For the SQL, please note that it is a bad idea to have just one SQL connection that gets re-used. There is a mechanism called [*connection pooling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) built in which makes the correct way of running a query a simple: create connection, use connection, dispose of the connection.

If you want to use a variable for the column name, then you have to concatenate it into the SQL query. This is open to SQL injection, so it is necessary to verify that a valid column name is being used before doing anything with it.

For the DateTimePickers, the value to use is the `.Value`, not the `.Text`, otherwise it could have problems with different Windows settings/locale.

So, this code is a starting point for getting it to work:

```vb
Private Function IsValidColumnName(colName As String) As Boolean
    'TODO: Put the valid column names in the array.
    Dim validColumnNames = {"Col1", "Col2", "ColWhatever"}
    Return validColumnNames.Any(Function(c) colName = c)

End Function

Private Sub UpdateDataInColumn(columnName As String, newData As String)
    If Not IsValidColumnName(columnName) Then
        Throw New Exception("Invalid column name [" & columnName & "]")
    End If

    Dim sql = "UPDATE tblWebaccessErrorTrack SET [" & columnName & "] & = @editData WHERE IssueDateTime BETWEEN @frmdate AND @todate AND ErrorDetails LIKE @errorDetails AND ClientIpaddress LIKE @IpAddress AND ResponseStatus LIKE @responseStatus AND TicketNo LIKE @ticketNo"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmdupdate As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@frmdate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = frm_DateTimePicker.Value
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@todate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = to_DateTimePicker.Value
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@errorDetails", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtErrorDetails.Text & "%"
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@IpAddress", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtClientIp.Text & "%"
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@responseStatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtResponseStatus.Text & "%"
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@ticketNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtTicketNo.Text & "%"
        cmdupdate.Parameters.Add("@editData", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = newData '//Data we give

        Dim nChanged = cmdupdate.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If nChanged > 1 Then
            ' More than one row was updated. This is probably a Big Problem.
        End If

    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub ShowDataGridView()
    'TODO: write the ShowDataGridView() sub.
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Update.Click
    Dim colName = "Some method to select a column would go here."
    Dim newData = txtEditdata.Text

    UpdateDataInColumn(colName, newData)
    ShowDataGridView()

End Sub
```